# Record a webcam video using HTML5 and then store it on a remote server

Tags: php, html, html5-video, html5-audio, html5boilerplate

I need to record a video on the client's machine using `HTML5` with permissions and then store them on a remote server.

I am new to HTML5. Please help me with the steps I should take care of, in order to do this.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Below is a tutorial from html5rocks which might help you get started.  

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Answer (score 0):

Html5 rocks is a very good tutorial. So, if you need a flash plugin or to be sure that works in all browser (I use it because my app must run in IE<10) use Scriptcam, easy to use. [Link](http://www.scriptcam.com/docs.cfm)